# Saving memory on pickle dumping

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I am facing a memory/swap problem when running a third party script to generate features for a deep learning model. I get this output when i run the script that generates these features and saves them to a pkl file:

```
generate unigram
Headline unigram done
Killed
```

The code snippet is:

```
    print "generate unigram"
    data["Headline_unigram"] = data["Headline"].map(lambda x: preprocess_data(x))
    print "Headline unigram done"
    data["articleBody_unigram"] = data["articleBody"].map(lambda x: preprocess_data(x))
    print "Body unigram done"

    print "generate bigram"
    join_str = "_"
    data["Headline_bigram"] = data["Headline_unigram"].map(lambda x: ngram.getBigram(x, join_str))
    print "Headline bigram done"
    data["articleBody_bigram"] = data["articleBody_unigram"].map(lambda x: ngram.getBigram(x, join_str))
    print "Body bigram done"

    print "generate trigram"
    join_str = "_"
    data["Headline_trigram"] = data["Headline_unigram"].map(lambda x: ngram.getTrigram(x, join_str))
    print "Headline trigram done"
    data["articleBody_trigram"] = data["articleBody_unigram"].map(lambda x: ngram.getTrigram(x, join_str))
    print "Body trigram done"

    with open(cwd+'data.pkl', 'wb') as outfile:
        cPickle.dump(data, outfile, -1)
        print 'dataframe saved in data.pkl'
```

it pretty much generates unigrams/bigrams/trigrams for two columns in a pandas dataframe. The object `data` is quite big, containing 900k entries and that is why I'm getting a RAM/swap problem. My question is, what is the right way of saving to the pickle file (aka dumping) after each row and releasing the memory used on this row. For example:

After doing

```
data["Headline_unigram"] = data["Headline"].map(lambda x: preprocess_data(x))
```

How can I save it to the .pkl file and release the memory being used by `data["Headline"]` without losing it's content? Since this is a third-party code, the modification should not alter at all the structure of `data.pkl`

Thanks,
Lucas.

Comment: One comment, not directly related to your question: You could simplify `data["Headline_unigram"] = data["Headline"].map(lambda x: preprocess_data(x))` to `data["Headline_unigram"] = data["Headline"].map(preprocess_data)`

Comment: This still holds to 2.7? Is there any memory gain on this modification?

Comment: Yes also for 2.7. Does not save any memory, just simplifies your code.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
with open("head_line.pkl", "wb") as fh:
    cPickle.dump(data["Headline"], fh)
del data["Headline"]
```

and so on...

But this would result in multiple files.

Additionally you can `import gc` at the beginning and then run `gc.collect` in between. But you can not rely that this deletes all unused objects.

Python should automatically free the memory once the object is used for the last time in the given execution environment. (see [gc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html))

Comment: will try and come back with an outcome. Thanks.

Comment: I just added aditional pickling in case you want to keep the headline entry from data.

Comment: I thought about that. Later I would have to merge the multiple files in a single one, do you think pandas has an efficient way of doing that, without loading everything into memory at a single time?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with the pickled data. Can you process files independently or do you need all data at the same time ?

Comment: Tried to load one column at a time, but still had memory issues. Will Dockerize it and send to DC/OS. Thanks for the answers